# send json with request to express in node

Tags: node.js, json, express, body-parser

I have 2 node js apps one sending a post request as follows:

```
request.post({
    url: url,
    headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
    json: {a:1,b:2}
},
    function (error, response, body) {
        //..
    }
);
```

and the other is trying to handle it with express and body-parser:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/verify', (req, res,cb = (err, res) => {}) => {
    var data =  req.body; //returns empty json!
    // ..
}
```

the problem is that at the receiving end I can't retrieve the json data I'm looking for. Does any body know what I'm missing?

Comment: Please tell what is url  ?

Comment: localhost, the other node js app that is running the express

Comment: Please share full url

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:4000/verify

Comment: Please use this code let options = {
    url: 'http://http://mockbin.com/request',
    form: {
        email: 'me@example.com',
        password: 'myPassword'
    }
};
request.post(options, callback);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to your server side code should work:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```